# How to start with FIWARE?

Tags: fiware

I'm new with FIWARE and I'm disoriented by the large amount of information related to this platform, the amount of components called Generic Enablers that exists. I don't know where to start.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to start would be the FIWARE [Developer's Website](https://www.fiware.org/developers/) - this gives you an overview as to what FIWARE is and how the various enablers fit together

[image]

- **Core Context Management** holds the state of the system and allows other elements to subscribe to changes of state
- **IoT and Robots** provides sensor data and transforms it into the NGSI standard interface
- **Processing/Analysis/Visualization** provides dashboards and complex event processing
- The pillar on the right - **API management** adds security, as well as interface to systems to publish data externally.
- **Deployment tools** helps the instantiation of a FIWARE system easier

If you are looking for more information, the [Tour Guide](https://fiwaretourguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) describes each enabler in depth and holds a series of link to Videos, User Guides, presentation and so on.

If you learn-by-doing the [Tutorials](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will present a series of exercises to build up a *"Powered by FIWARE"* application - it also describes how various Generic enablers fit together. The first six tutorial concentrate on the use of the Orion Context Broker which forms the central block of FIWARE.

Basically the the [NGSI](https://orioncontextbroker.docs.apiary.io/) v2 standard provides a common interface to allow a series of disparate building blocks to talk to each other using a common language, these are things you're probably going to need in a generic Smart application, but are not unique to your application - you would be providing the "special sauce" by either creating custom sensors sending context data into the system (i.e. the block at the bottom), or complex processing algorithms which are reading and altering the context state (i.e. the block at the top).

If you want to speed development you can *buy-not-build* and use the existing free open source generic enablers. The whole system is modular so its easier to experiment and add and refactor things as necessary.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jason Fox answer,

Every year the FIWARE foundation organizes summits, that are pretty good. There are tutorials and hands on sessions, and all slides I think that are available [here](https://www.slideshare.net/FI-WARE/). It could also be a good starting point

On the other hand, most of the FIWARE software components (GEs), are available in [Docker HUB](https://hub.docker.com/u/fiware/). Therefore, if you feel comfortable using Docker you could set up a bunch of FIWARE GEs in a few minutes.

Finally, there is this [FIWARE-IOT-Stack](https://fiware-iot-stack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) website, where you can find a kind of FIWARE architecture for IoT. I do not know if it's official, but in my case it was very useful.

Regards!